# Logout issue in web app

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have had this odd behaviour I have an asp.net web application.

On the loginview it calls the following to log out

```
protected void Unnamed_LoggingOut(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
    {
      Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
    }
```

Now this works in the root of the website and in the Account subfolder and another Admin subfolder, but I have yet another subfolder that it just will not work in, I tracked an issue in the javascript when I click the Login Status to log off

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['mainForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.mainForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

I get this on the theForm.submit();

```
 Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

MyDetails:179 __doPostBackMsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81:1 Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._doPostBackMsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81:1 (anonymous function)VM138:1 (anonymous function)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the HTML for your ``<form>`` element? Is there by any chance an ``<input name="submit">`` inside it? That could potentially override the ``submit`` function with a named value, which would explain why it's an object.

Comment: "If a form control (such as a submit button) has a name or id of submit it will mask the form's submit method." quoted from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit

Comment: That was it, you star, I never noticed it, thanks so much that has been driving me mad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any further information, the most likely problem from what I can tell is that your form contains an `<input>` or a `<button>` with either an `id` or `name` attribute set to `"submit"`. This will cause `theForm.submit` to return that element instead of the `submit` function as you would expect it to. My suggestion is a little hacky, but should hopefully fix the problem. Instead of

```
theForm.submit();
```

try

```
document.createElement('form').submit.call(theForm);
```

If this works, then what I assumed to be the problem was it.

**EDIT**: As suggested, a more permanent solution is to change the `id` or `name` to something else in order to prevent accidental interference.

Comment: I changed the id's of my buttons, which is better i think as it actually prompted me to make them more meaningful, thanks again